# Which org settings are included in a org shape?

Tags: metadata-api, org-shape, bot-settings

Per this document https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_shape_intro.htm, org shape should include

> Features, Metadata API settings, edition, limits, and licenses
> determine what we refer to as an org’s shape. For further
> clarification, org shape includes:
>
> Metadata API settings with boolean fields.

Bot Settings enablement is Metadata API Setting which has boolean field but it is not enabled via org shape.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BotSettings xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <enableBots>true</enableBots>
</BotSettings>
```

Why?

How should be determine which Metadata API settings with boolean fields included or excluded from org shape?